# What is "Hierarchial Parent" and is it crucial for a new activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to the whole Android thing.

Currently, I'm trying to create a new Activity for my app and I was asked to specify the "Hierarchial Parent" for my new activity.

[image]

So is it crucial for an Activity? (I.e. will my program crash if I don't specify it?)
What is it for?

The Android developer website used the example:
Hierarchial Parent: com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity

Is it syntactic? (It looks like package name + parent class name)

Thanks in advance :}